# FIlter specific email in my json data using gson

Tags: android, gson

This is the json:

```
{
    "ad_id":"27",
    "ad_title":"Catering",
    "com_name":"Yen Catering",
    "sup_email":"all_cool@gmail.com",
    "sup_hp":"012-4826105",
    "sup_category":"Food",
    "sup_price":"100",
    "sup_location":"No.110, Jalan Angsana Sari 8, Taman Angsana Sari, 08000 Sungai Petani, Kedah.",
    "sup_desc":"Food catering for wedding ceremony, house warming and more...",
    "img_name":"Food.jpg",
    "img_link":"http:\/\/www.bruhnancel.xyz\/FYP\/photo\/Food.jpg",
    "img_path":"photo\/Food.jpg",
    "img_type":"image\/jpeg",
    "like":"1",
    "dislike":"0",
    "email":"zz@hotmail.com"
},
{
    "ad_id":"26",
    "ad_title":"Chocolate",
    "com_name":"Chocolate",
    "sup_email":"dgbzuana@gmail.com",
    "sup_hp":"012-8210976",
    "sup_category":"Dessert",
    "sup_price":"40",
    "sup_location":"Kota Kinabalu, Sabah",
    "sup_desc":"Served delicious chocolate..",
    "img_name":"Chocolate.jpg",
    "img_link":"http:\/\/www.bruhnancel.xyz\/FYP\/photo\/Chocolate.jpg",
    "img_path":"photo\/Chocolate.jpg",
    "img_type":"image\/jpeg",
    "like":"0",
    "dislike":"0",
    "email":"zz@hotmail.com"
},
{
    "ad_id":"23",
    "ad_title":"Mascot",
    "com_name":"HappyDay",
    "sup_email":"hd@hotmail.com",
    "sup_hp":"013-8867908",
    "sup_category":"Entertainment",
    "sup_price":"60",
    "sup_location":"Kota Kinabalu, Sabah",
    "sup_desc":"Bring me to your birthday party, school function and more.. ",
    "img_name":"Mascot.jpg",
    "img_link":"http:\/\/www.bruhnancel.xyz\/FYP\/photo\/Mascot.jpg",
    "img_path":"photo\/Mascot.jpg",
    "img_type":"image\/jpeg",
    "like":"0",
    "dislike":"0",
    "email":"haha@hotmail.com"
}
```

and this is my code that i have wrote...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listOfAds;
    private Gson gson;
    private AsyncHttpClient client;
    private ResponseObject responseObj;
    private BrenAdapter mAdapter;
    private String url = "http://www.bruhnancel.xyz/hope.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listOfAds = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(MainActivity.this, url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                String ResponseStr = new String(responseBody);
                gson = new Gson();
                responseObj = gson.fromJson(ResponseStr, ResponseObject.class);
                final List<ResponseObject.UserinfoEntity> userinfo = new ArrayList<ResponseObject.UserinfoEntity>();
                for (ResponseObject.UserinfoEntity data : userinfo){

                    String email = data.getEmail();
                    if(email.equalsIgnoreCase("zz@hotmail.com")){
                        userinfo.add(data);
                    }
                }
                mAdapter = new BrenAdapter(getApplicationContext(),responseObj.getUserinfo());
                listOfAds.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my ResponceObject

```
public class ResponseObject {

    private List<UserinfoEntity> userinfo;

    public void setUserinfo(List<UserinfoEntity> userinfo) {
        this.userinfo = userinfo;
    }

    public List<UserinfoEntity> getUserinfo() {
        return userinfo;
    }

    public static class UserinfoEntity {
        private String ad_id;
        private String ad_title;
        private String com_name;
        private String sup_email;
        private String sup_hp;
        private String sup_category;
        private String sup_price;
        private String sup_location;
        private String sup_desc;
        private String img_name;
        private String img_link;
        private String img_path;
        private String img_type;
        private String like;
        private String dislike;
        private String email;

        public void setAd_id(String ad_id) {
            this.ad_id = ad_id;
        }

        public void setAd_title(String ad_title) {
            this.ad_title = ad_title;
        }

        public void setCom_name(String com_name) {
            this.com_name = com_name;
        }

        public void setSup_email(String sup_email) {
            this.sup_email = sup_email;
        }

        public void setSup_hp(String sup_hp) {
            this.sup_hp = sup_hp;
        }

        public void setSup_category(String sup_category) {
            this.sup_category = sup_category;
        }

        public void setSup_price(String sup_price) {
            this.sup_price = sup_price;
        }

        public void setSup_location(String sup_location) {
            this.sup_location = sup_location;
        }

        public void setSup_desc(String sup_desc) {
            this.sup_desc = sup_desc;
        }

        public void setImg_name(String img_name) {
            this.img_name = img_name;
        }

        public void setImg_link(String img_link) {
            this.img_link = img_link;
        }

        public void setImg_path(String img_path) {
            this.img_path = img_path;
        }

        public void setImg_type(String img_type) {
            this.img_type = img_type;
        }

        public void setLike(String like) {
            this.like = like;
        }

        public void setDislike(String dislike) {
            this.dislike = dislike;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getAd_id() {
            return ad_id;
        }

        public String getAd_title() {
            return ad_title;
        }

        public String getCom_name() {
            return com_name;
        }

        public String getSup_email() {
            return sup_email;
        }

        public String getSup_hp() {
            return sup_hp;
        }

        public String getSup_category() {
            return sup_category;
        }

        public String getSup_price() {
            return sup_price;
        }

        public String getSup_location() {
            return sup_location;
        }

        public String getSup_desc() {
            return sup_desc;
        }

        public String getImg_name() {
            return img_name;
        }

        public String getImg_link() {
            return img_link;
        }

        public String getImg_path() {
            return img_path;
        }

        public String getImg_type() {
            return img_type;
        }

        public String getLike() {
            return like;
        }

        public String getDislike() {
            return dislike;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to filter according to email
Example like my json i want to only filter email which is "zz@hotmail.com"

I have try and it still wouldnt filter to what i need, anyone help me please tq.

Comment: Show `ResponseObject ` class code also

Comment: I have edited my post , please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Tomato, see my answer probably help

Answer (score 0):

Problem is :

```
for (ResponseObject.UserinfoEntity data : userinfo){
                                           ^^^^^^
 ....
}
```

Need to use `responseObj. getUserinfo()` instead of `userinfo` for getting `UserinfoEntity` because `userinfo` ArrayList is declare or initialized just before for loop:

```
for (ResponseObject.UserinfoEntity data : responseObj.getUserinfo()){
                                           ^^^^^^
 ....
}
```

Comment: @TomatoJuice: show your updated code and also use `mAdapter = new BrenAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userinfo);`

Comment: Ur solution work! thanks!

for (ResponseObject.UserinfoEntity data : responseObj.getUserinfo()){
                                           ^^^^^^
 ....
}

mAdapter = new BrenAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userinfo)

After i change this, everything work just as i want it.Thanks!